# Why JsonResult needs to implement both IActionResult and IStatusCodeActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, interface, jsonresult

JsonResult's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnetcore-5.0) (also we can see this if we <kbd>F12</kbd> into `JsonResult`'s definition in Visual Studio)

> Implements IActionResult, IStatusCodeActionResult

My question is why does it need to implement both of these interfaces ?

[IStatusCodeActionResult's doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.istatuscodeactionresult?view=aspnetcore-5.0) says it already implemented `IActionResult`

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. If it implements IStatusActioNResult it already implicitly implements the IActionResult, (since it inherits from it) that's what the docs say. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Tseng sorry for being unclear. I'll rephrase my question a bit: Why is it implemented like this: `JsonResult : IStatusCodeActionResult, IActionResult` instead of simply `JsonResult : IStatusCodeActionResult` ? The later option should be sufficient, shouldn't it ?

Comment: It doesn't, as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v5.0.10/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/JsonResult.cs#L15]). In .NET 5.0 it's as `public class JsonResult : ActionResult, IStatusCodeActionResult` in the source code

Answer (score 1):

Because JsonResult needs the IStatusCodeActionResult property StatusCode, and the method ExecuteResultAsync (ActionContext context) only.

this is designed so that you can just call

```
public IActionResult ActionMethod()
```

from the Asp.Net Controllers.

If they created the class like this:

```
public class JsonResult : IStatusCodeActionResult
```

Then you are required to change the action method to

```
public IStatusCodeActionResult ActionMethod()
```

Developers now would not have the flexibility of returning other responses base on the interactions with the user/client.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your answer correctly. Let's say they created the class like `JsonResult : IStatusCodeActionResult`. In this case I can still use `public IActionResult ActionMethod()`, no ? Because `IStatusCodeActionResult` is already a subtype of `IActionResult`

Answer (score 0):

Credits to @Tseng's comment.

The [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v5.0.10/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/JsonResult.cs) for `JsonResult` here doesn't implement both interfaces.